# For loop is creating vector when I want a scalar

Tags: r, for-loop, random, simulation

If you examine the code below, I'm trying to run a simulation where the data is sampled every year for 10 years for 100 orders.  The simulation works fine for the first 10 years of order 1, but when it comes to order 2 it tacks the value onto order 1, i.e., creates a vector rather than gives me a scalar.  This messes up my output and I don't know how to fix it.

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(30,600,sd=100),rnorm(30,300,sd=50),rnorm(30,200,sd=50),rnorm(30,600,sd=100)))
colnames(dat) <- c("unused","apr","oct","used")

  unused <- NULL
  deduct <- NULL
  carryover <- NULL
  used <- NULL
  apr <- NULL
  oct <- NULL
  available <- NULL

  #_____________________________________ Sample Data _____________________________________________________
  for (i in 1:100) {   #increment for orders
    for (k in 1:10){   #increment for years
      if(k==1) {
        subsample <- dat[sample(seq_along(dat[, 1]), size = 1,replace=TRUE), c("unused", "apr","oct","used")]
      } else {
        subsample <- dat[sample(seq_along(dat[, 1]), size = 1,replace=TRUE), c("apr","oct","used")]
      }
      if (k==1) unused[i] <-subsample$unused
      apr[i] <- subsample$apr
      oct[i] <- subsample$oct
      used[i] <- subsample$used
      #print(subsample)
      #_____________________________________ Use Data _____________________________________________________
      if (unused[i] > 200) {
        deduct[i] <- unused[i]-200
        carryover[i] <- 200
        available[i] <- carryover[i]+apr[i]+oct[i]
      }

      if (unused[i] <= 200) {
        deduct[i] <- 0
        carryover[i] <- unused[i]
        available[i] <- carryover[i]+apr[i]+oct[i]
      }

      #_____________________________________ Create unused for next year _______________________________
      unused <- available-used

    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused, R doesn't really have scalars, everything is a vector. What is the exact output you are expecting? This `for` loop doesn't "return" anything so I'm not sure what output you are looking at. It's very unclear what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: How about I call it a single element vector rather than a scalar.  I kept out the write statements to make the code less cumbersome, but the problem really occurs when i = 2  and k=1.  Instead of sampling a returning a value, it returns the previous value from i=1 and the new value as a 2 element vector.  I just want to have the new value overwrite the old value.

Comment: I still don't understand what part of the code you are talking about or what the problem is. Is this about the `sample()` function? Maybe also use `set.seed()` so we can generate the exact same values as you.

Comment: My guess would be that you want to replace 'unused[i]' everywhere in your code with just 'unused'. And this line unused <- available-used with unused <- available[i] - used[i]

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer.  Yes, I'm talking about the sampling.  If i=1, it works fine for k=1:10, but as soon as i=2 and k=1, the new value is tacked onto the value from i=1 and k=1.  For example, let's say at i=1 and k=1 the value is 200 for unused.  At i=2 and k=1, the new value is 230.  Instead of getting unused =230, I will get unused = 200  230.

Comment: Replacing unused[i] (or any variable that has [i]) doesn't correct the problem.

Comment: By using `used[i] <- subsample$used` you make `used` a vector of length `i`. Substracting it from `available` you make `unused` a vector of length `i`, as well. This is what you have to fix.